# I want to understand why this warning is coming along when i try to compile and run the following program,

Tags: java, arrays, generics

i have included the source here,, can anyone help me understand it.

```
  Program 1: TEST CLIENT

     public class bl_stack_gtestClient{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

     bl_stack_array <String> s = new bl_stack_array <String> (20);
     int i =0;
     while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        String item = StdIn.readString();
        if (!item.equals("-"))
          s.push(item);
        else if (!s.isEmpty()){
            StdOut.print(s.pop() + " ");
        }
      }
      StdOut.println("(" + s.size() + " left on stack)");
     }
    }
```

This program is my stack implementation using Arrays,
program 2 :

```
   public class bl_stack_array <E> {
      private Object[] stack;
      private int ptr=0;

      public bl_stack_array(int capacity){
        stack = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
      }

      public void push(E item){
        stack[ptr++] = item;
      }

     public E pop(){
       E temp = (E)stack[--ptr];
       stack[ptr] = null;
       return temp;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
      return ptr == 0; 
    }

    public int size(){
      return ptr;
    }

   public void print(){
     for (int i =0; i < ptr ; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(" "+stack[i]);
     }
  }
```

}

TO compile in Terminal,

```
    javac -Xlint -cp ".:stdlib.jar" bl_stack_array.java
    javac -Xlint -cp ".:stdlib.jar" bl_stack_gtestClient.java
```

To run

```
     javac -cp ".:stdlib.jar" bl_stack_gtestClient
```

The warning i got is this,

```
       bl_stack_array.java:5: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
       stack = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
                  ^
      required: E[]
      found:    Object[]
      where E is a type-variable:
      E extends Object declared in class bl_stack_array
      bl_stack_array.java:11: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
      E temp = (E)stack[--ptr];
                     ^
     required: E
     found:    Object
     where E is a type-variable:
     E extends Object declared in class bl_stack_array
```

2 warnings

Please help me to understand the warning, i cant really understand, why the warning arises, but i still did the casting,
But the program works fine,

is there any way to get rid of this warning,... or to use generics array[] , E[], not just primitive

Comment: `is there any way to get rid of this warning` --> `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: You could try: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: well this is not the way you use generics ofc the warning is thrown ..

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the cast that is raising the warning is useless. You are instantiating an `Object[]` and assigning it to a variable which is declared as `Object[]`, so why do you want to cast it? The only cast you should perform is the one in the `pop` method. I think the warning in this case means the compiler cannot make sure that what you are doing is legal, but the program works anyway because you really are casting `Object[]` to `Object[]`. Generics as far as I know cannot be used with primitive types (i.e. arrays), it is only useful in `Object`s (i.e. full-fledged classes, and in Java all of them do extend `java.lang.Object`).

Comment: Good example of how Generics and Arrays don't work too well in Java is build-in `Array.newInstance()`. One wold expect it to be typesafe `<T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> componentType, int length)` but it is just `Object newInstance(Class componentType, int length)` instead.